# LG G Pad 8.3 Google Play edition - not recognized by Eclipse (Windows) & Solution

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

Actions tried:

- Installed LG PC Suite -- does not recognized 8.3 ... part of problem because it's Play Edition???
- Checking and unchecking "USB Debugging" - windows make a sound, but still not seen.
- Removed SD Card, rebooted.
- Google USB Driver is installed in SDK

Finally went to this page, after download the zip, and followed instructions (while my windows has a Amd64, I had to pick i386 to get the driver appearing).
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Android Composite ADB Interface

How I see it in Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Finally went to this page, after download the zip, and followed instructions (while my windows has a Amd64, I had to pick i386 to get the driver appearing). http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Android Composite ADB Interface

How I see it in Eclipse...